# ExtJS 6.7 Modern - Define unchecked value for a checkbox

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

Is there is an easy way to define unchecked value for a checkbox in ExtJS 6.7 modern toolkit? Like [Ext.form.field.Checkbox.uncheckedValue](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html#cfg-uncheckedValue) in classic toolkit.

At the first glance I should override Ext.form.field.Checkbox or use [Ext.data.writer.Writer.transform](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.data.writer.Writer.html#cfg-transform) in modern and it seems like overkill for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern toolkit - there isn't `uncheckedValue` in `checkboxfield`.

I guess you're using `record.set(form.getValues());` and next `store.sync()` so you can do what you said (override `checkbox` or use `Ext.data.writer.Writer.transform`) or you can use [serialize](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-serialize) in model.

> A function which converts the Model's value for this Field into a form which can be used by whatever Ext.data.writer.Writer is being used to sync data with the server.

Example:

```
 Ext.define('App.model.Test', {
      fields: [{ 
           name: 'status', 
           type: 'auto',
           serialize: function (value, record) {
                if(value === 1){
                     return "success";
                } else {
                     return "failed";
                }
           }
      }]
 });
```